# How does mainstream Christianity view "Heaven is for Real"?

Tags: books

I was looking for books on what happens after death on Amazon, and came across [Heaven is for Real: A Little Boy's Astounding Story of His Trip to Heaven and Back](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0849946158). I found this [interesting review](http://www.reclaimingthemind.org/blog/2011/02/book-review-heaven-is-for-real/) but I didn't get anything conclusive out of it.

I understand that there is a very fine line between using external sources to illuminate Bible verses and being deceived by the devil as in [2 Corinthians 11:14](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%2011:14&version=NIV).

What is the biblical/Christian way to deal with this book (and others just like it)?

1. completely ignore it (since the Bible is sufficient)
2. read it, but only skeptically at an intellectual level
3. be prepared, because weird things = the end is near
4. [your answer here] ...

Comment: At a more technical level: near death experiences, by their very nature, are hugely dubious accounts: you have a body that is failing, with likely cerebral hypoxia combined with a random rush of crazy hormones, and quite likely hysteria. This is *not* a good combination for making a reliable and accurate observation on the world.

Comment: @Caleb: I disagree; I think the [*original question*](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/revisions/9011/1) was not "all over the place." It's probably not the most concise wording, and the formatting could use some work, but I found it reasonably intelligible. Over the space of just a week or two, the OP seems to be investing noticeably greater effort in crafting questions, and should be commended, not rebuked.

Comment: @JBunyan: :-) I think Caleb's point is valid. There is a dichotomy of (1) the body of the question being focused specifically on "Heaven is For Real", yet (2) the [old] title of the question being fairly general on "Near Death Experiences."

Comment: Hah! That's great -- and notice that I called it a "reasonably intelligible," not "great" question! FWIW, I think you're doing a good job. The speed with which you seem to be learning about Christianity is impressive and encouraging. Cheers.

Comment: @JBunyan: Point taken. I was a little hash there. However, this was towards the end editing a whole series of questions for clarity. Most of the others from this OP I could see what the main question was, but I failed when I tried to edit this one because it seemed to have multiple prongs going on and I thought the OP needed to pick the focus rather than me as an editor. I did commend the OP for their effort in some previous comments, and the edit they made on this one to clarify that it was about this book was just the ticket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many, many things out there that claims similar events happening in their lives. 
Obviously, it is common sense not to believe all those stories.
One story consists of someone visiting hell; one story consists of person going heaven and back.Some stories even tell the tale of being on footsteps on heaven.

How do we deal with these stories?
Here is the general answer:
Use Bible as Reference.

Check every aspect of the story to the Bible. If they disagree on certain aspects, than the story is *definitely* wrong.

Bible is not just some sort of story we consult. Bible is The Word.

> "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God." - John 1:1.

Everything in the Bible is true, and will be proven true.

> "For truly I tell you, until heaven and earth disappear, not the smallest letter, not the least stroke of a pen, will by any means disappear from the Law until everything is accomplished." - Matthew 5:18

Comment: According to which denomination or Christian group is "logos" in John 1:1 synonymous with the Bible?